# Passing JSON object from $http.get to function

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object which I load using `$http.get` like this:

```
$http.get("getData.php")//getData.php returns a J son file
    .success(function(response) {$scope.data = response;});
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "1": "*/3 * * * *",
        "2": "*/6 * * * *",
        "3": "*/3 * * * *",
        "4": "* * * * *"
    },
    "2": {
        "1": "*/3 * * * *",
        "2": "*/2 * * * *",
        "3": "*/3 * * * *",
        "4": "* * * * *"
    }
}
```

How can I pass this object to a function under the same controller and access its content?

I tried a few variations, most intuitive was this:

```
   $scope.compare = function (data){
        return data[1][1];
    }
```

But none of my attempts worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data[0][0]` does not reference any items in your JSON object.

`data[1][1]` would return `"*\/3 * * * *"`
`data[1][2]` would return `"*\/6 * * * *"`

In the square brackets, you need to use the **keys** you defined in the JSON object because this data is an *object*, not an array.

[Simple Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/qLfw54ky/)

Comment: Without seeing your full application running, this will be difficult to debug (your issue could be that data is being referenced in the function before it gets a value assigned to it). Can you check in your function to ensure data actually has a value? (i,e, `console.log(data);`... this will tell you if `data` is being passed properly.)

Comment: guessing its kind of stupid but how can i get the number of the array?

Comment: I played around with the circumstance of your application in angular a bit and I think if you handle your compare function a little differently it might work better:  `$scope.compare = function() { return $scope.data[1][1]; }`
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/puxwc6q2/4/)

Comment: @Al.s what do you mean by the 'number of the array'?

Comment: sorry i ment the sub-array number, there is sub-array '1' and '2', im trying to get this number with ng-repeat but im only able to get  the values inside those sub-array's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70585/discussion-between-jrulle-and-al-s). -- [demo for your ng-repeat question](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/puxwc6q2/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The array starts with `"1"`.

Try:

```
data["1"]["1"]
```

or

```
data[1][1]
```